# How to redirect Hard Coded Urls to hard coded Urls without hitting errorAction?

Tags: .htaccess, yii2, redirect

I have almost one thousand links which I want to redirect when a request is made specifically to those URLs. e.g

```
Redirect http://serverAddress/app/2017/06/09/8-20-taraweeh/ http://serverAddress/app/prayer/8-or-20-Rakat-for-Taraweeh
```

I am trying this code in .htaccess file but the problem is that when I enter the Url, instead of hitting the .htaccess code it first hits the Yii app and check if the Url exists, if not exists(definitely does not exist) it takes me to the error page. 
Now I cannot define a rule because as you can see the URL after the app is changing, I cannot define a generic rule. So I have to hard code in my yii2 app. 

**Question:**
How to Hard code Url redirections in yii2?

Comment: at which particular position are you using the above code , you should add complete `.htaccess` file with one sample link,, and are you using advance or basic app ? for basic it should be inside the `web` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a rule something similar:

```
'<year:\d+>/<month:\d+>/<day:\d+>/<title>' => 'site/redirect'
```

Then in your SiteController use can use redirect in the controller action:

```
public function redirectAction($year, $month, $day, $title) {
    $newUrl = ....  // compute new URL based on the parameters
    return $this->redirect($newUrl, 301);
}
```